# Is there any package available for FIEGARCH modelling in R, Eviews or any other software?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, modeling

I searched at various places but didn't find any relevant packages for this. I need to know how people proceed with FIEGARCH Modelling in any software.

Answer (score 0):

you can use oxmetric or s_pluse software for this work.

Comment: Please add a pointer to relevant sites or documentation (if available, otherwise give OP a hint where to get further info), as-is Your answer is "a bit too terse". Thanks for the effort, though!